# How many axioms can you remove from ZF set theory and still have an "interesting" version of mathematics?

Tags: alternative-set-theories

Obviously you can remove the axiom of choice from ZFC set theory to get ZF set theory. Using ZF only you can still construct most of mathematics and proofs.

This led me to wonder how many more axioms could you remove and still form some kind of complicated quasi-mathematical structure. In the sense that one could combine the axioms together to create theorems that are non-trivial and non-predictable?

As the axioms are similar to string replacement rules, I would imagine you could create interesting theorems starting with just 2 axioms.

The list of axioms are:

1. Axiom of extensionality
2. Axiom of regularity
3. Axiom schema of specification
4. Axiom of pairing
5. Axiom of union
6. Axiom schema of replacement
7. Axiom of infinity
8. Axiom of power set
9. Well-ordering theorem OR axiom of choice.

How many could you remove and still have an intersting quasi-set theory?

I would define "interesting" in this sense as that a theorem would have a non-obvious proof.

Perhaps even some axioms are not needed in much of modern mathematics?

Comment: Specific axioms are rather accidental things, one can formulate an equivalent theory with a different list of axioms. The real question is how much weaker than ZF a set theory can be and still be "interesting", see e.g. [Weak Systems of Set Theory Related to HOL](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-58450-1_43.pdf). Quine even opined that [second order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#SetTheoSheeClot) by itself is already "set theory in sheep’s clothing”.

Comment: [General set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_set_theory) of Boolos is a fragment of ZF (even Z) "sufficient for all mathematics not requiring infinite sets, and is the weakest known set theory whose theorems include the Peano axioms".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the stance

> I would define "interesting" in this sense as that a theorem would have a non-obvious proof

entirely seriously, one sufficient criterion for interestingness in this case would be **essential incompleteness**: a consistent computably axiomatizable theory is essentially incomplete iff it has no consistent computable completion. Note that this is stronger than mere incompleteness; for example, the theory of algebraically closed fields is computably axiomatizable and incomplete, but is contained in the computable consistent complete theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $17$.

It turns out that essential incompleteness shows up quite early on indeed! For example, [Montagna and Mancini showed](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-35/issue-2/A-minimal-predicative-set-theory/10.1305/ndjfl/1094061860.full) that we already wind up with an essentially incomplete theory once we can show that the empty set exists and that we can always adjoin new individual elements to existing sets. In fact (this really just follows from the same argument), the problem of deciding which sentences are theorems of this theory $\mathsf{N}$ is exactly as hard as the problem of deciding which sentences are theorems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I guess another way to define 'interesting' is to say there there is no program that will prove (reduce to axioms) a statement in a known amount of time. i.e. we don't know if the program will terminate. I assume that is the same as what you're saying? But at the same time, this might not necessarily make the scheme interesting... just hard.

Comment: @zooby Yup, from any sort of decision problem perspective the extraordinarily weak theory $\mathsf{N}$ will be as complicated as, for instance, $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: As an aside, (elementary) Euclidean geometry is decidable, but, arguably, still "interesting". Are there set theories of this sort? I am guessing this requires the decision algorithm to be sufficiently "intractable".

Comment: @Conifold Would [set-theoretic mereology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06593) count?